# How to get hash keys in order of their appearance

Tags: hash, raku

I have a hash:

```
use v6;

my %some-hash = a => 0,
                b => 42,
                c => 417;
```

and I'm trying to get its keys with `%some-hash.keys`, which returns a Seq of all keys but not in the order in which they were declared. It seems that the order of keys is determined at hash initialization, because it changes if I run the code several times.

Is it possible to preserve the order `(a b c)`?

P.S. `%some-hash.keys.sort` will not suffice, since keys are expected to have arbitrary names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hash keys are randomly ordered, as you have seen.

There are modules in the ecosystem that could help you get what you want:

- [OrderedHash](https://modules.raku.org/dist/OrderedHash)
- [ArrayHash](https://modules.raku.org/dist/ArrayHash)

Or if these don't do exactly what you want, you can build your own Hash implementation with:

- [Hash::Agnostic](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Hash::Agnostic)